# Arangodb pagination with AQL /_api/cursor instead of /_api/simple/all

Tags: arangodb, aql

Arangodb has a LIMIT and SKIP function for simple queries, how would one implement using /api/cursor

```
FOR product in products
    LIMIT 2
return product
```

Ideally something like

```
FOR product in products
    LIMIT 20 SKIP 10
return product
```

Or it this only support using `/_api/simple/all` calls

Answer (score 6):

Think I figured it out, the LIMIT clause has an offset, count, that can be used to skip and implement pagination.

```
LIMIT @offset, @count

FOR product in products
    LIMIT 2, 10
return product
```

Comment: To add a little bit of explanation: `LIMIT` comes in two forms, `LIMIT count` to return up to `count` documents and `LIMIT offset, count` to skip `offset` documents and return no more than `count` documents. You can think of the former as a shorthand for `LIMIT 0, count` (don't skip any documents, then return `count` documents tops). https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/Operations.html#limit